# MFMailComposeViewController attachment file size limit

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using `MFMailComposeViewController` to send a file. Everything works fine with files under 15mb. Anything over, and the file simply doesn't get attached to the `MFMailComposeViewController` view.  It's not that the email server isn't accepting, its that it never gets attached in the first place.

Does anyone have any ideas if there's a way to resolve that?

I know many email services can't handle attachments over 5 or 10mb, but other services allow you much larger file size.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", NSHomeDirectory(), @"Documents", fileName];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:path]; //also tried dataWithContentsOfFile with same results
[mail addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"audio/x-caf" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf", label]];
[appDelegate.tabBarController presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading a 15 MB *anything* into RAM on a pre-2009 iPhone or iPod is going to really push the limits of your process's available memory, so it's not surprising there's a cap.  I wouldn't try to convince the compose view to accept a larger attachment; instead, I'd suggest you transfer the file to some external server and either e-mail a link to it or send the mail from there.

Comment: shouldn't the point of using dataWithContentsOfMappedFile be that the email can be sent without actually reading the whole file into memory at one time?

Comment: Whether this is possible or not also depends on whether the system's mail spooler is also able and willing to page off of disk; my guess is that it's building the whole MIME message in RAM anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it has a 21mb limit (relevant to iOS 15). But I could sent at least 24mb when pressed Try. 25mb couldn't be attached and MFMailComposeViewController was closed by system at all.

[image]